# How to send basic HTTP GET via proxy from GAE Java?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-maps, proxy, httpconnection

I 'm getting 620 error response codes back from the google maps geocoding api if i send the request directly from my app engine servlet, so i have no choice but to use a proxy to receive a successful response.  I set up a proxy server, and ive tested it from several computers.  Now, all I want to do is make a url request from my GAE servlet through my proxy.

I've tried every possible solution out there and none of them work....

-java.net.Proxy isnt supported in the app engine runtime...
-setting properties as follows:

Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("http.proxyHost", "proxyhostname");
props.put("http.proxyPort", "proxyhostport");

didnt do anything.

What is the easiest way to send an http GET via a proxy in app engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like this is not possible: Google's App Engine APIs don't support it. Using a third-party library (like Apache's HTTPCore/HTTPClient) or writing it yourself is not possible because essential network classes like java.net.Socket are not [whitelisted](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html).

Not sure why you can't access the Google Map API, but if that really does not work, your only choice is to write some application on your proxy server that responds to normal HTTP requests and then forwards them to Google Maps.

*Update:* Googled a bit, seems like a [well-known problem](http://gaengine.blogspot.com/2010/05/google-maps-api-quotas-and-app-engine.html): the Map API has a limit of 2500 requests per day and IP, and this is limit is reached quickly on GAE where you share your IP with many other applications. The only thing you can do is move the requests to the client, use some proxy with own IP, or use a different service.

Comment: I've complaining all over the place on the App Engine groups about the  GAE ips not being whitelisted on the maps server.  No one seems to give a shit.  Is it really true that its literally impossible to make a simple http request to the maps api from GAE without using some incredibly roundabout technique?